# Render Multiple React Components from the AJAX Response

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render multiple components from the response of an Ajax call, here is the sample response data of that call.

```css
{
  "componentList": [
    {
      'componentLabel': 'Hey Folks',
      "dataSource": "local",
      'templateType': 'typeone'
    },
    {
      "componentLabel": "Hey Folks",
      "templateType": "typetwo",
      "dataSource": "api",
      "api": "URL to get Data of This Template"
    },
    {
      'componentLabel': 'Hey Folks',
      "dataSource": "local",
      'templateType': 'typethree'
    },
    {
      "componentLabel": "Hey Folks",
      "templateType": "typefour",
      "dataSource": "api",
      "api": "URL to get Data of This Template"
    },
    {
      'componentLabel': 'Hey Folks',
      "dataSource": "local",
      'templateType': 'typefive'
    },
    {
      "componentLabel": "Hey Folks",
      "templateType": "typesix",
      "dataSource": "api",
      "api": "URL to get Data of This Template"
    },
    {
      'componentLabel': 'Hey Folks',
      "dataSource": "local",
      'templateType': 'typeseven'
    },
    {
      "componentLabel": "Hey Folks",
      "templateType": "typeeight",
      "dataSource": "api",
      "api": "URL to get Data of This Template"
    },
    {
      'componentLabel': 'Hey Folks',
      "dataSource": "local",
      'templateType': 'typenine'
    },
    {
      "componentLabel": "Hey Folks",
      "templateType": "typeten",
      "dataSource": "api",
      "api": "URL to get Data of This Template"
    }    
  ]
}
```

And following is the main component class that generates view to the page:

```css
import React from 'react';

class ComponentList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes = [];
  }
  
  getComponentView(data) {
 switch(data.templateType) {
  case 'typeone':
   if(data.dataSource === 'local') {
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeOne content={'data from local Storage'} />);
   } else {
    let componentData = "get component's data from ajax call";
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeOne content={componentData} />);
   }
  case 'typetwo':
   if(data.dataSource === 'local') {
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeTwo content={'data from local Storage'} />);
   } else {
    let componentData = "get component's data from ajax call";
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeTwo content={componentData} />);
   }
  case 'typethree':
   if(data.dataSource === 'local') {
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeThree content={'data from local Storage'} />);
   } else {
    let componentData = "get component's data from ajax call";
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeThree content={componentData} />);
   }
  case 'typefour':
   if(data.dataSource === 'local') {
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeFour content={'data from local Storage'} />);
   } else {
    let componentData = "get component's data from ajax call";
    this.state.componentVirtualNodes.push(<typeFour content={componentData} />);
   }
       // And so on for the rest of the type of templates
 }
}

  render() {
    let responseData = 'Response from the structure Ajax Call';
    responseData.map( singleComponent =>  this.getComponentView(singleComponent));
    return (
      <div className="component-wrapper">
        {this.state.componentVirtualNodes}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ComponentList;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The above code to generate components is working fine for the components whose data is available in local storage. But the components whose data is coming from the another Ajax apis are not rendering and i think, reason for that is that data is ready for them since they are coming from another AJAX.

I hope i am clear with the question, please let me know if you need some other detail. Any kind of help is most appreciated.

I tried maintaining a react state to hold the object of virtual nodes in hope that whenever state will update, view will be rendered. But that is not working.
I also tried component's `forceUpdate()` method too but that is also not helping.

While i was searching over internet and found that `componentDidMount()` or `componentWillReceiveProps()` can be helpful for such things but i don't know how to use them for my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have your function that makes the ajax call return a `promise` to return the result when the same is available. When the promise is complete, you render the component. You can look into this library `Q` for using promises.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/q

Comment: Yes I am using `promise`. I am using `babel` as a `transpiler`, so i think `Q`  is not require. `promise` will get data asynchronously, but it doesn't help rendering a component synchronously. Please correct me if i am wrong. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: **pressing enter button posts comment here, weird behavior :)** here is the edited comment 
Yes I am using promise. I am using babel as a transpiler, so i think Q is not require. promise will get data asynchronously, but it doesn't help rendering a component asynchronously. Please correct me if i am wrong. An example would be appreciated.